# Getting specific hub instance associated with a specific SignalRConnectionId

Tags: signalr

Getting a reference to the client using the SignalRConnectionId is pretty simple via the `GlobalHost` class. Is there a way to get a reference to a hub instance associated with that client/connection? In other words, given the client connection Guid, can I get a reference to a hub instance that's talking to that client? The reason I want to do this is so I can invoke an instance method on the hub from somewhere else in the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to get a Hub instance from outside of the [SignalR Hub pipeline](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubpipeline) or the Hub itself.

Hubs are ephemeral in SignalR. Generally a new Hub is instantiated for each invocation, and then disposed immediately after.

This means that a single WebSocket connection can have an arbitrary number of associated Hub instances over its lifetime. Moreover, unless there is an ongoing invocation, it's unlikely that there is even an associated Hub in existence.

I would suggest replicating the Hub instance method you want to call with a static method that takes an `IHubContext` as a parameter. You can get the `IHubContext` using [GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub).

Comment: This makes perfect sense, except it seems weird that to get the IHubContext from within the hub itself I can't just do this.Context, instead, I need to use GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<THub> as from anywhere else in the code